# smtp configuration for custom gmail address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, smtp, gmail

For my rails application, i have configured my gmail address as a gateway to send emails, i did this and it was working fine (normal gmail) :

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
port:                 587,
domain:               'example.com',
user_name:            'example@gmail.com',
password:             'password',
authentication:       'plain',
enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

But today, i created a custom email in gmail (contact@mydomain.ma).
So i did the same configuration beside confirming that the domain is mine:
1 - Enable Forwarding and POP/IMAP
2 - Enable access of less secure apps
and for the rails configuration, i did the following:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
port:                 587,
domain:               'mydomain.ma',
user_name:            'contact@mydomain.ma',
password:             'password',
authentication:       'plain',
enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

Infortunately, i get this error :

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError at /fr/emails
534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtx
```

I'm sure that the error cames from the rails configuration, any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for port, but AFAIR gmail uses 465 SSL port. Have you tried port 465?

Also check this article http://docs.helpscout.net/article/120-smtp-settings

There's info that sometimes google treats some apps for 'less secure' and requires more setup.

> **I've put in my credentials correctly, but I keep receiving a 5.7.14**
>   **error when I test the connection. Help!** This means Gmail is trying to
>   properly authenticate your credentials through Help Scout. In some
>   cases, you have to ask Gmail to  allow less secure apps in order for
>   this to do the trick. If it's still acting wonky, head over to this
>   link, follow the instructions, and then head back into Help Scout and
>   retry the Test Connection button in your connection settings.

Check this links:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en
https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Hope this helps.